# Enable textbox for a radiobuttonlist one of the listitem value using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

script for enable/disable

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function display() {
     if (document.getElementById("<%=Institution.ClientID %>").value == "others") {
         document.getElementById('<%= lblSpecify.ClientID %>').style.visiblity = "visible";
         document.getElementById('<%= InstituteOthers.ClientID %>').style.visiblity = "visible";
     }
     else {
         document.getElementById('<%= lblSpecify.ClientID %>').style.visiblity = "hidden";
         document.getElementById('<%= InstituteOthers.ClientID %>').style.visiblity = "hidden";
     }

 }

</script>
```

If 5th listitem(AnyOther) is selected then only label(lblSpecify) and textbox(InstituteOthers)  should be visible=true ,otherwise visible=false

> Why did you choose our Institution:
>
> 1Doctor
>          2WordofMouth
>           3Camps
>            4OldPatients
>             5AnyOther
>
> > 
>
> ```
>   </td>
>      <td>
>         <asp:Label ID="lblSpecify" runat="server" Text="Specify :" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
>     </td>
>     <td>
>         <asp:TextBox ID="InstituteOthers" runat="server"  TabIndex="18" MaxLength="20" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
>     </td>
>
>  </tr>
>  </table>
> ```

But it is not effecting.please help.

i am calling the script in

> > onchange="display"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  TabIndex="18" >

Answer (score 1):

There is also OnSeletedIndexChanged event exists on radiobuttonlist you can hide and dispaly textboxes on the value selected.

For doing this in javascript try below script

```
var list = document.getElementById(<%=Institution.ClientID %>);
var inputs = list.getElementsByTagName("input");
 var selected;
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
          selected = inputs[i];
          break;
       }
  }
  if (selected.value == "others") {
       document.getElementById('<%= lblSpecify.ClientID %>').style.visiblity =   "visible";
       document.getElementById('<%= InstituteOthers.ClientID %>').style.visiblity = "visible";
  }
```

Comment: whrere should i call this function in radio button

Comment: Call this on onclick of radio button

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the where you are calling display method.

If there is dropdown list on your page you can do this on selectedindex change event.

Comment: ya..i am calling in radiobuttonlist onchange="display"